# specman error - Specman run reached the tick_max configuration limit

Tags: specman

I am running a specman environment and I get the error:
"Specman run reached the tick_max configuration limit(10000) without a call to stop_run() "
How can I debug this error? 
I guess I have some kind of an unresolved loop with no time progress. How can I find the place (file and row number) where the simulator is stuck?
I have tried to use break on error - but it does nothing...
Thanks

Comment: Was the simulation time still progressing before this?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous comment about progressing of the simulation, you may want to try increasing the no. of ticks by the following command:
*config run -tick_max=MAX_INT*
and then hitting the interrupt button or Ctrl C when simualtion stop progressing and check the stack in specman debugger.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that when I increase tick max its ok